# Does "share perspectives" mean the same as "share the same perspectives"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The freelancer I hired who is a native speaker said "if you are only trying to stretch the answer to get to a certain number of words or characters, then put in “the same”.  Otherwise, they are extraneous and make it too wordy." Is this true? "Share perspectives" means exactly the same as "share **the same** perspectives" and I don't need "the same"?

> Although our lives may be easier with friends who **share perspectives**
> on everything, it is better to have friends who disagree now and then
> because those disagreements can foster personal growth.

Comment: It could mean 'share one another's perspectives'. I would suggest **share our perspectives**.

Comment: Based on this series of questions, sounds like your editor needs an editor.

Comment: @gotube, god he has a phd at Texas Tech University. He literally rewrote every sentence of mine regardless it's good or bad.

Comment: @Learner110 Not a PhD in editing, I hope.